# Pass data to a groupLabel

Tags: docusignapi

I can pass data to text labels but can't workout how to include data needs mapping to a Radio group.  I think I need to create a separate array for Group Labels but can't find any help on this.

Below is a snippet of my code which works fine except my attempt to pass a value to my `first_life_title` radio group.

I tried both groupName and tabLabel for the radio group.

```
array(
    "email" => $toemail, 
    "name" => $recipientName, 
    "roleName" => $templateRoleName,
    "tabs" => array( 
                "textTabs" => array (
                     array (
                        "tabLabel" => "firstlife",
                        "value" => $name
                    ),
                    array (
                        "groupName" => "first_life_title",
                        "value" => $title
                    ),
```

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, you're specifying the Radio Group tabs within the `textTabs` array -- you should instead specify `radioGroupTabs` as a *peer* of the `textTabs` array. Here's the JSON that shows the correct structure -- notice that the `radioGroupTabs` array contains a `groupName` property as well as a `radios` property (which is itself an array, containing a single object to specify the radio button to select):

```
"textTabs": [
    {
        "value": "sample string 11",
        "tabLabel": "sample string 19"
    }
],
"radioGroupTabs": [
    {
        "groupName": "NAME_OF_RADIO_GROUP",
        "radios": [
            {
                "value": "VALUE_OF_RADIO_BUTTON_TO_SELECT",
                "selected": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Kim, big help.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer adequately addressed your question, can you please mark it as "accepted" (so that others are more likely to benefit from this information in the future)? Thanks!